# VB Script or Tool for converting Excel to Word (Not tables)

Tags: vbscript

I have a Excel sheet with N number of rows and M no.of Columns (Its not a table). I want to Convert this excel to Word document where i want the data in columns to be filled line by line in the word document. Is this possible ? or else Any tool is already available ?

Comment: Yes its possible. You need to write a vba code for it

Comment: Can you provide any example ? I am not aware of this

Comment: Refer the link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/